# Grub not appearing after installing windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, elementary

I'm really new to the linux world. I currently have installed Elementary OS Freya (ubuntu 14.04 based). I had three partitions. One for / , one for linux-swap and one for /home,  all ext4. I created one to install windows 10. Then I had to convert my disk to MBR because it was GPT. Grub got destroyed, but after using boot-repair I was able to boot my linux.

Then I installed Windows 10 on its NTFS partition and grub disappeared. I tried using boot-repair twice and didn't do anything. (Windows 10 is properly booting). I tried using grub-install from a live elementary-os CD but got some weird errors like:

```
error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.
```

I checked the directory /usr/lib/grub and found x86_64-efi. So I tried:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda1 --target=x86_64-efi --root-directory=/mnt
```

and still got errors. Any help will be greatly appreciated, I don't wanna loose my linux. I spent a lot of time configuring it.

Here is the pasteBin from boot-repair [pasteBin](http://paste2.org/jZL8b9cF)

EDIT:
Here is the output from fdisk -l

```
  Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000345a3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    78125055    39061504    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        78125056    87889919     4882432    1  FAT12
/dev/sda3        87889920   205076479    58593280    1  FAT12
/dev/sda4       205076480   348436479    71680000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

The / was supposed to be installed on the first partition /dev/sda1. 
Here is the output if I mount that partition

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo ls -l /mnt
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root   8192 Feb 10  2016 Boot
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 Feb 10 04:35 BootInfo
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 400228 Oct 30 07:18 bootmgr
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      1 Oct 30 07:18 BOOTNXT
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 Feb 10 04:35 boot-sav
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   8192 Feb 10  2016 BOOTSECT.BAK
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 Feb 10 04:27 oldbooot
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 Feb 10  2016 Recovery
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      0 Feb 10  2016 System Volume Information
```

I am new on linux, but these files do not seem right. It appears that windows wiped out my linux.

Comment: @Ashu I noticed the link don't appear if it's styled as code. I edited the post.

Comment: I don't have any idea why my question was downvoted. Anyway, nevermind. I realized windows wiped my linux partition to install its boot mechanism in the first partiton (linux). So I reinstalled everything again.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your pastebin contents there are 3 red flags:

> **What is sdb1?**
>   __________________________________________________________________________ It is vfat and contains the following Boot files:
>   /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
>                      /EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys
>
> =================== UEFI/Legacy mode: **This live-session is not in EFI-mode. SecureBoot maybe enabled.**
>
> =================== **Suggested repair The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would restore the [(generic mbr)] MBR in sda, and
>   make it boot on sda1.** Additional repair would be performed:
>   unhide-bootmenu-10s   fix-windows-boot

**So essentially you need to disable secure boot. Make sure both the O/S are getting installed in EFI mode. And also let boot repair restore generic MBR in sda.**

Comment: sdb is a HDD I had connected via USB. 
I googled a bit about secure boot but I don't have that option neither in windows 10 nor my bios. My pc is kinda old. What do you mean by getting installed in EFI mode?